# Deleting folder in windows 10 with special characters in folder name

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have the following folder getting created when I run a process:

`Intel® VTune™ Profiler Results`

Note the special characters for "Registered" and "Trade Mark". I am having a tough time deleting this folder (this folder is not empty and has contents inside it) via normal command line of `cmd.exe`.

Previous answers to similar questions have suggested to run `dir /x` to know the "short" name for this folder, see for e.g., [here](https://superuser.com/a/72296/1246360)

However, running `dir /x` does not reveal the "short" name for this folder -- the column where this short name is revealed is empty.

The following works from within Powershell:

`rd Intel*`

This asks to confirm whether I would like to delete given that this folder has subfolders and files within them.

How can similar effect be obtained using a batch file that has this delete command that is intended to be run via `cmd.exe`? [That is, I just want to double click the batch file and under default mode where the batch file commands are run within `cmd.exe` effect this deletion]

Comment: Pragmatically speaking (it'll be slow), you can call PowerShell from your batch file: `powershell.exe -c rd -Recurse Intel*` - `-Recurse` suppresses the confirmation prompt.

Comment: Thanks. I am able to confirm that this works from `cmd.exe`, however, from within the batch file, as part of other commands, this seems ineffective. Let me test more. Ideally, this would be the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create utf8 file like that:

```
chcp 65001
rd "Intel® VTune™ Profiler Results"
```

this is hex view of it:

```
63 68 63 70 20 36 35 30 │ 30 31 0D 0A 72 64 20 22  chcp 65001♪◙rd "
49 6E 74 65 6C C2 AE 20 │ 56 54 75 6E 65 E2 84 A2  Intel®› VTune™››
20 50 72 6F 66 69 6C 65 │ 72 20 52 65 73 75 6C 74   Profiler Result
73 22 0D 0A             │                          s"♪◙
```

Comment: @Tryer probably your folder name contains some more symbols, try to run chcp and then `dir > test` to get real utf8 name

Comment: Indeed, this works beautifully. Just curious regarding `chcp 65001` since there are other commands that follow this particular `rd` command, is there a risk that `chcp` setting applies to other folders for which I was not needing them before? In other words, is it okay to have this `chcp` setting always?

Comment: @Tryer chcp changes "code page", so 2 byte symbol like `®` (hex `C2 AE`) is considered as one, not as two, it does not affect how things works with standard ascii single byte symbols

Comment: Just wanted to add that since this folder was not empty (as indicated in my OP), I had to suffix the command with `/s/q` -- it would not work otherwise -- `cmd` was kind enough to let me know that it is not deleting the folder due to its nonempty interiors -- for future folks that may come across this accepted answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%z IN ('DIR /s /b /ad int*') DO RD /s /q "%%z"
```

Noting that it would delete all directories starting `intel`

For the missing shortname problem, Microsoft has apparently changed the default for shortname-generation to OFF. Here's some docco on rectifying this:
[8.3 filename generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-8dot3name)

Comment: Just so I understand it clearer, `/s` lists all folders and files matching the wildchar, `/b` is only the filename/foldername `/ad` is only directories. could you provide some tips for `/f` and `delims=` -- what they achieve? Finally, is there a need for the last `%%z` to be within quotes? I suppose the first `%%z` earlier in the command is capturing it for subsequent use later.

Comment: Many examples on SO about this - documentation is `for /?` from the prompt. `/f` makes `for` operate in a mode to process the quoted command as a text list. By default, each line is tokenised; `delims=` turns the tokenising off. Yes - `%%z` needs to be quoted because the directoryname may contain separators like SPACE. The quotes are harmless if included, but if omitted and the name includes separators, the `rd` command would see more than one argument, so it might not  act as expected. The `/s` on the `dir` subcommand processes all subdirectories and the "listing" contain complete pathnames.

Answer (score 1):

An **alternative** to [Iłya Bursov's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77231483/45375), ***without* the need to change the active code page**:

```
for /d %%d in ("Intel? VTune? Profiler Results") do rd /s /q "%%d"
```

- The problematic characters, `®` and `™`, were replaced with wildcard character `?` (which matches any single char). Using the full name with only those selective substitutions minimizes the risk of false positives.
- `for /d` loops over matching *directories* (`/d`).
- `rd`'s `/s` option also removes the target directory's *content* (if any), and `/q`  does so quietly, i.e. without prompting.

Apparently, with `rd`, only matching the problematic name by wildcard *indirectly*, via `for /d`, works properly (by contrast, both `rd /s /q "Intel? VTune? Profiler Results"` and
`rd /s /q Intel*` result in error `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` Curiously, direct use of wildcards does work with `dir`.)

---

To provide **background information** as well as an enhancement to Iłya's answer:

The **root of the problem** is ***character encoding***:

- The active [*code page*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) of a console window, as reported by `chcp`, defaults to the *OEM* character encoding, as determined by the legacy system locale.

  - `cmd.exe` uses this encoding to interpret batch files, well-behaved programs use it to decode and encode their in- and output, and `cmd.exe`'s redirections (`>`) use it.
  - On US-English systems, for instance, the OEM code page is [437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), and its character set does *not* include `®` and `™`
- By **switching to the [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) code page with `chcp 65001`**, these characters *can* be represented, but it's **important** to note that:

  - Your **batch file must be saved as UTF-8 too, *without* a BOM** (due to `chcp 65001` being called from *inside* the batch file).<sup>[1]</sup>
  - **`chcp` changes the active code page *for the remainder of the `cmd.exe` session*** (i.e. the executing `cmd.exe` process); that is, it changes how other batch files are read, the encoding used in program output, as well as the encoding used in output redirections (`>`).

    - To avoid that, you can *save and explicitly restore the original code page* as follows:

      ```
      :: Save the current code page.
      for /f "delims=: tokens=2" %%n in ('chcp') do set "prevCodePage=%%n"

      :: Switch to UTF-8
      chcp 65001 >NUL

      :: Now you can remove the directory.
      rd /s /q "Intel® VTune™ Profiler Results"

      :: Restore the previous code page.
      chcp %prevCodePage% >NUL
      ```
    - That said, in the case of launching your batch file via double-clicking from File Explorer or the desktop, the changed code page is *not* a concern, given that when the batch file exits, so does the session as a whole.
  - **Note**: A radical alternative would be to switch to UTF-8 *system-wide*, as one-time configuration, in which case both the OEM and ANSI code pages would be set to `65001`. However, this has has far-reaching consequences - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) for details.

---

<sup>[1] Surprisingly, `cmd.exe` apparently reads batch files *line by line* so that a `chcp` call *inside* a batch file can change how the *subsequent lines* are decoded. However, unless code page `65001` is already in effect *before* the batch file's first line is read, a UTF-8 BOM would be misinterpreted *as data*, and cause the command on that first line (typically, `@echo off`) to malfunction.</sup>

Comment: Is there a way to go to `cmd.exe` and check the current codepage? I am worried if due to my execution of the batchfile with `chcp 65001` in it, it has changed that setting computer wide and whether this change is not reset even after restarting the computer. You do state that it remains so for the "remainder of the session" -- does this mean the changed chcp persists only until that particular `cmd.exe` window is open and once I close it, for the rest of the computer and `cmd.exe` sessions, it reverts to the original chcp?

Comment: @Tryer, yes, it affects that particular session (the specific `cmd.exe` _process_) only. `chcp` can _not_ change the code page _persistently_.

Comment: On my machine, the command you have provided as is, translates to :
`for / %d in ("Intel? VTune? Profiler Results") do rd /s /q "%d"` when run from within the batch file. So, the first `/d` renders as `/`. Is there a way to prevent this and faithfully have the batch file provide `/d` ?

Comment: @Tryer, I see: You're not using `@echo off` at the start of the batch file and that's how the command is _echoed_. When commands are echoed, `%%` in `for` statements turns into single `%` (this is how you'd have to formulate the statement if you executed directly in an interactive `cmd.exe` session). I have no idea wy the `d` disappears from `/d`, but that is merely a _display bug_ - it doesn't affect the _functionality_ of the batch file.